# Get unique id of specific element in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my Firebase database structured like this:

```
{
  "userProfile" : {
     "X0u2SEFfYEeVmdw4TXl58ou2eYy1" : {
        "email" : "jane@yahoo.com",
         "name" : "Jane"
      },
      "cliv7hQ4FsWKTtYksPDXcdDafdi2" : {
         "email" : "doe@gmail.com",
          "name" : "John Doe",
       }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the unique id of the element that matches query criteria, for example the key of the element with email equal to doe@gmail.com.

I'm doing this by using:

```
firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once( 'value', data => {
    let user = data.val();
});
```

This returns me the entire object with that email, but I only want its unique id ("cliv7hQ4FsWKTtYksPDXcdDafdi2" in this case). What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email);
query.once( 'value', data => {
    data.forEach(userSnapshot => {
        let user = userSnapshot.val();
        let key = userSnapshot.key;
    });
});
```